# htop 100% fake CPU load

Tags: linux, debian, central-processing-unit, top, htop

Recently my VPS show 100% CPU usage of all cores in htop and observium, but there is no process that uses > 5% CPU. In fact, the statistics of my VPS host shows there is no activity at all. Is this a bug? I've read something about a leap second. But the most answers doesn't help me.

PS: top shows there is no CPU usage.
PPS: I'm running debian 8

screenshots:

**htop**
[image: htop]

**Top**
[image: top]

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31971/why-does-htop-meter-show-90-while-table-is-0-0

Answer (score 1):

Htop does not know it is running on a kernel level VPS and is showing the CPU usage of the hardware, not just your VPS.

Comment: Maybe, but when I reboot the VPS. htop works fine.